# Flutter search text out of html content's visible text

Tags: html, flutter, dart, search, mobile

In my app there is a search feature to filter message list by user entered search text. But my message items' body field contains a full formatted HTML document (`<html>...</html>`). I want to filter the message list by applying the search filtration to message body field.

```
 _getFilteredMessageList() {
    if (!StringHelper.isNullOrWhiteSpace(this._searchText)) {
      return _messagesList.where((msg) => msg.title.toLowerCase().contains(this._searchText.toLowerCase()) || msg.body.toLowerCase().contains(this._searchText.toLowerCase())).toList();
    }
    return _messagesList;
  }
```

Here the `msg.body` is the HTML content field.

**I want to search by the user visible text content only, ignoring all the non-visual tags and comments.**

Is there any package or a logic to implement this functionality in Flutter?

**Flutter v2.2.2**

Comment: Please share your code to get better answer.

Comment: @Diwyansh updated by adding the filtration code.

Comment: I recommend you to parse the html content which makes it very easy to filter out the list. You could use [`html`](https://pub.dev/packages/html) package for parsing. It is simple to use.

Comment: @SandunPerera try this package to parse html to String https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html

Comment: can you provide a sample code as I need **HTML to plain text parser** by ignoring all non-visual html content and extract only the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution from web, sample code as below.

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart';

static String getHTMLBodyPlainTextFromHTMLDocument(String htmlString) {
  var document = parse(htmlString);
  String parsedString = parse(document.body!.text).documentElement!.text;
  // parsedString = StringHelper.removeLineBreaks(parsedString);
  // parsedString = StringHelper.repalceMultipleSpacesWithSingleSpace(parsedString);
  return parsedString.trim();
}
```

Above method will give you plain text that is visible to user in the WebView widget as well and it will **completely strip off html tags and non-visual elements. But there will be lots of unnecassary spaces within the plain text** that we have to **remove them seperately** to defrag the text with proper spacing just to save variable memory size.

The commented two lines of above code does the removal of line breaks and extra spaces as a separate helper method manually written.

Comment: using this code for https://google.com I also get js code, functions specifically. Is it possible to filter them?